# How to retain Apache airflow DAG's data in the Rancher-desktop - Kubernetes pod, when Rancher-desktop is restarted

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, rancher-desktop

I have installed rancher desktop and created a Kubernetes pod.

Inside the pod I have installed Apache Airflow and created some DAG's tested and saved them.

When I exit rancher desktop and switch off my PC and restart rancher desktop next day all the data is lost which I saved inside the pod.

Can you please help how can we save the data even when we restart the rancher-desktop

Comment: please share how you created the pod. Data loss most probably related to pod definition, not Rancher desktop configuration

Comment: Using Devspace i created the pod. Check the link below for Devspace.

https://www.devspace.sh/docs/getting-started/development

Comment: please provide more details (steps you took) so your question and problem would be clear and reproducible

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes pods are based on docker containers which are stateless by default, in order to create stateful applications on K8S, we use [persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) to store all the data we want to persist when the pod restart. So you need to add a persistent volumes by creating a [persistent volume claim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reserving-a-persistentvolume), then [load and mount the claim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#claims-as-volumes) to the Airflow container in the pod, and write the dags files to the mount path.